# How to splice the specific index using the IndexOf method of javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have module where I need to uncheck or check the data using checkbox. Now the problem is I need to slice the push value if the user uncheck it based on the target value. Currently when i try to console log the index it result -1 meaning: "it is not present" I will show you guys my sample code and sample attached image for the reference to make more detailed..

Code:

```
        var array = [...this.state.checkboxVal]; 

        
        console.log(e.target.value,"my index")

        var index = array.indexOf(parseInt(e.target.value));

        console.log(index);

        if (index > -1) {
            array.splice(index, 1);
            
            await this.setState({ checkboxVal: array });
        }


        console.log(this.state.checkboxVal);
```

The Expected Output: The Index 1 should be remove

[image: Output]

Comment: While React state updates are asynchronously processed, `this.setState` isn't an `async` function, it can't be awaited.

Comment: the value of e.target.value is 22

Comment: @DrewReese sorry for that Will change this soon. thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are comparing incompatible types, "number" vs "array", so a match can never be found.

If you are simply wanting to remove an element from an array in state in React, using a [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a common pattern.

```
const targetValue = Number(e.target.value);
this.setState(prevState => ({
  checkboxVal: prevState.checkboxVal.filter(([val]) => val !== targetValue),
}));
```

The filter callback `([val]) => val !== targetValue` is taking the array element and uses destructuring assignment to get the value stored in index 0 and name it `val` and then return only the elements with a `val` ***not equal*** to the event's target value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are storing an array of arrays so you are trying to compare `number` to `array` and apparently it will return `-1`. To solve this you can use `findIndex` function in the following way.

```
        var value = parseInt(e.target.value);
        var index = array.findIndex((element) => element[0] === value);
```

NOTE: Please use `let` and `const` these are latest way to define your variables.

Answer (score 1):

In your array, every element is an array (for example: [30, "2021-05-17"]). But you are now checking only the value whether it's present or not.
You have to check `[30, "2021-05-17"]` whether it's present or not.

Here's an example:

```js
const arr = [[30, "2021-05-17"], [50, "2021-05-17"], [20, "2021-05-17"]];
const valueToDelete = 20;

const newArray = arr.filter(item => item[0] !== valueToDelete);

console.log(newArray);
```

In your case this would be:

```js
var array = [...this.state.checkboxVal]; 

const newArray = array.filter(item => item[0] !== parseInt(e.target.value));

console.log(newArray);

this.setState({ checkboxVal: newArray });
```

Hope this will help you brother. Thank you. :)